# What is the proper way to configure child routes under the hostnames in ZF2 router config?

Tags: zend-framework2

**Scenario:**

There is a zf2 app named fabric which includes two different modules named "bike" and "car" and provides similar (but not same) functionality via following url structures:

```
+------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
|     Hostname     | Part  |          Page           |   Module    |   Controller    | Action |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
| www.fabric.dev   | /     | Company homepage        | Application | IndexController | index  |
| bikes.fabric.dev | /     | Homepage for bikes      | Bike        | IndexController | index  |
| bikes.fabric.dev | /list | Listing of bikes        | Bike        | ListController  | list   |
| cars.fabric.dev  | /     | Homepage for cars       | Car         | IndexController | index  |
| cars.fabric.dev  | /list | Listing of bikes        | Car         | ListController  | list   |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
```

So,

- Application, Bike and Car are different modules and namespaces `\Application`, `\Bike` `\Car`
- There are 3 vhost (www..,cars..,bikes..) on http server which points to same directory: `/www/fabric.dev/public`
- Every module have their own routing definitions in module.config.php files respectively like non-working sample below:

  ```
  // module/Application/config/module.config.php
  'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
       'home' => array(
         'type'    => 'Hostname',
         'options' => array(
             'route' => 'www.fabric.dev',
             'defaults' => array(
               '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller'
               'controller'    => 'Application\Controller\Index',
               'action'        => 'index',
             ),
          )
       )
     )
   );
  ```

and

```
    // module/Bike/config/module.config.php
    'router' => array(
      'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
        'type'    => 'Hostname',
        'options' => array(
            'route' =>  'bikes.fabric.dev',
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Bike\Controller'
                'controller'    => 'Bike\Controller\Index',
                'action'        => 'index',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/list',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Bike\Controller\List',
                        'action'        => 'list',
                    ),
                  ),
               ),
            ),
         ),
       )
    )
```

**Problem and question**

There is enough documentation exists on the web about zf2's routing classes like hostname, segment, literal and regex separately but not about **how-to-pair** and use these fantastic classes together.

Is there any proper way to provide the uri schemes above using router configuration other than copying all application source code to separate vhost directory?

Comment: There's no way you can have the routing you desire by configuration alone. There has to be some lower level checking to decide which of your module routes ought to be loaded based on the hostname. At the routing stage its already too late to do that, it just gets the merged routes from all modules, which would be Bikes and Cars combined and using the `home` route and hostname from whichever module happens to be loaded last.

Comment: Actually i'm doing same thing via just loading required modules for related hostname. Common module is Application, when i call www.fabric.dev bike and car modules are not loading but when i call bike.fabric.dev application + bike modules are loading. Same think at cars.fabric.dev, just application + car modules are loading.

Comment: What would be "used together"? I don't get the question? Do you want to re-use code between the modules? Why do you need to "copying all code". Based on your comments, do you wan to load the modules lazily?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how routing works. A route is based on a *key* and contains some options. All configuration (including routes) from all modules are combined into one config array.

This means if you have a route `home` defined in your Application and then have the **same** route `home` in Bike, the Bike will override the home from Application.

It's better to have route names based on your namespace as well. So the application routes:

```
'router' => array(
  'routes' => array(
     'home' => array(
       // config here
     )
   )
 );
```

And the bike routes

```
'router' => array(
  'routes' => array(
     'bike' => array(
       // config here
     )
   )
 );
```

Notice the difference from `home` to `bike` in the second example!